# How save the rename value to database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I had edited the device name and I want to save the edited value to database but it was not saving.

```
String strSQL = "UPDATE DeviceDetails SET devicename ='"+ edittext.getText().toString() +"'  WHERE uuid = '"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))+"'" ;
db.select(strSQL);
```

and the following is my database adapter.in this i did to exec the query and save to database but it is not.

```
                   public class DataBaseAdapter {

 public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    public static final String UUID = "uuid";
    public static final String DEVICENAME = "devicename";
    public static final String LIGHT = "light";
    public static final String ALARM ="alarm";


    private static final String TAG = "DDAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DeviceAdapter.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "DeviceDetails";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

   private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
       "create table DeviceDetails (uuid varchar(50) primary key  , " +
                                    "devicename varchar(50) ,light varchar(50),alarm varchar(50));";



    private final Context context;    

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DataBaseAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }



        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            try {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
           } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");


            Log.i("i am in onUpgrade", ""+db);

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DeviceDetails");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }    

    public DataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }


    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    public long insertData(String uuid,String devicename ,String light,String alarm ) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(UUID, uuid);
        initialValues.put(DEVICENAME, devicename);
        initialValues.put(LIGHT, light);
        initialValues.put(ALARM, alarm);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }




public Cursor getData(){
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {UUID,DEVICENAME,LIGHT,ALARM,
                }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

  public Cursor select(String query) throws SQLException {
        return db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }

/* public void select(String query) throws SQLException {
         db.execSQL(query, null);
    }*/
  public long updateName( String newName) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DEVICENAME, newName);
        return db.replace(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
        //(DATABASE_TABLE, values, DEVICENAME + " = '" + newName + "", null);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
e.g. you want to update the DEVICENAME where UUID is _uuid.
Then use like

public long updateName( String newName, String _uuid) 
{
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(DEVICENAME, newName);
   return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values,UUID + "= ?",new String[] { uuid});
}
```

Comment: i want to update only the devicename using the uuid because uuid is primary key.it should not be duplicate in table.

Comment: when uuid is primary key then it is not duplicate. call the method and pass the uuid for which you want to update the device name.

Comment: i did like this but not updating db.updateData(pos, edittext.getText().toString(),"off","off"); in edit class and database adapter i did public long updateData(String uuid,String devicename ,String light,String alarm ) { ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues(); initialValues.put(UUID, uuid); initialValues.put(DEVICENAME, devicename); initialValues.put(LIGHT, light); initialValues.put(ALARM, alarm); return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues); }

Comment: First make sure what you want means want to update or insert. 
Your code is saying you want to insert but you are saying you want update.
If you want update then why you are putting uuid in ContentValues and second point call the update not insert.
Have a look carefully again on my code.
It will work fine.

Comment: public long updateData(String uuid,String devicename ,String light,String alarm ) 
{ 
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues(); 

initialValues.put(DEVICENAME, devicename); 
initialValues.put(LIGHT, light); 
initialValues.put(ALARM, alarm); 

return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values,UUID + "= ?",new String[] { uuid});
}

Comment: ok i want update only i dont know so i did like that i apply this code and say to u the result

Comment: hi thanks i got but i had other issue that when move backward and forward it is not stable and when i close and open app default value i got but it should first check database and if it is null then it should have default value but i saved the value na   it is in my device scan activity

Comment: if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0){
           db.open();
         if(db!=null)
         {
           Cursor c=db.getData();
           if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
                if(deviceId.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))))
         {
   viewHolder.deviceName.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("devicename")));
   }
          else
          {
            mBluetoothAdapter.setName("NONAME");    
          }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
       }
         }
      db.close();
         }

Comment: For that first check into db

Comment: String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER_DETAILS;
cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

while (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
// Save values in list/some datastorage object
}

Accept ans if this helped you

Comment: Dear please first my comment.
you are doing Cursor c=db.getData();
but i am say do like
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER_DETAILS; cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

Comment: it works thanks a lot.but i had another issue.it is that when it first it is checking database and when i enter next activity and then to settings option whatever text is there in edit text it is returning that without modifying but in that textview i want present device name.

Comment: Make a new question for this. and if this ans helped you then accept it so that i can help other

Comment: ok i will add new question.can u provide me ur mail address to clear my questions like this.

Comment: i had toggle buttons in my app. i add off in datbase.if the user selects on/off that state should be constant through the app.

Comment: hi answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601735/how-to-get-access-to-toggle-buttons?noredirect=1#comment34413412_22601735

Comment: ajit r u there help me

Comment: answer this ajit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603869/how-to-have-the-require-listview-as-i-rename. plaese help me.

Comment: answer this ajit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296028/how-to-writecharacterstics-in-bluetooth-when-button-is-clicked

Comment: i am unable to post questions why

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices

1) execSQL:

```
 ...
 String strSQL = "UPDATE DeviceDetails SET devicename ='"+ 
                 edittext.getText().toString() +
                 "'  WHERE uuid = '"+
                 c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))+"'" ;
 db.execSQL(String sql)
 ...
```

Or 2) you can use update: (see @ajit code for a more fitting example regarding this, he uses UUID better)

```
public long updateName(String newName, String uuid) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(UUID, uuid);
    values.put(DEVICENAME, newName);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null);
    //(DATABASE_TABLE, values, DEVICENAME + " = '" + newName + "", null);
}
```

Comment: 1) i used but it asked to create a method in database adapter.

Comment: Ok, but now you have all information you need, between all the answers, you should be able to build something quickly.

Comment: i build but not replacing see public void execSQL(String strSQL) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  db.execSQL(strSQL, null);

Answer (score 0):

which is similar to insert db , instead of db.insert() we have to use db.update() as below,

```
  ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    //update column where u want to update for example,

    initialValues.put(DEVICENAME, devicename);
   db.update((DATABASE_TABLE, initialValues ,UUID+" = "+ uuid+ "", null);
```

Comment: hi,again i have to add all fields

Comment: you can update all column of the database table or you can just put your update column there that will update table based on condition

Comment: if you are messed up again, send me your update column  names will change according your requirement.

Comment: ok will do help for me i will sent u full project in that like this few issues are there will u solve i was tired last week onwards i am doing but not coming.

Comment: i did like this but not updating    db.updateData(pos, edittext.getText().toString(),"off","off"); in edit class and database adapter i did          public long updateData(String uuid,String devicename ,String light,String alarm ) 
     {
         ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
         initialValues.put(UUID, uuid);
         initialValues.put(DEVICENAME, devicename);
         initialValues.put(LIGHT, light);
         initialValues.put(ALARM, alarm);
         return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
     }

Answer (score 0):

```
String strSQL = "UPDATE DeviceDetails SET devicename ='"+ edittext.getText().toString() +"'  WHERE uuid = '"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))+"'" ;
db.rawQuery(strSQL);
```

try this

Comment: i did it is not updating when i retrive devicename i got previous value only not updated value.

Comment: whatever i edit in edittext it should get into the devicename field in database

Comment: try this...  SQLiteDatabase sqdb=dbcreator.getWritableDatabase();     make sure ur creating writable database   and use given query

Comment: @user254633 Happy to help,If this answer helped you,then please mark it as accepted,so it may help others also.Enjoy coding.